# ArrayList adding and removing Objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm working on an android application where I have to use custom listview with checkboxes. When user checks/unchecks, I need to add/remove objects in array list respectively.

here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    selectedView=view;
    System.out.println("Position of list item:"+position);
    if(parent.getAdapter().equals(categoryAdapter))
    {       
        System.out.println("First Adapter");        
        fl=new FoodList();      
        System.out.println("Tag:"+view.getTag());
        btOrder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        addToOrder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonSeperator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        fl.bundleCategory=fc.list[position];        
        fl.foodListService();       
        checks=new SparseBooleanArray();        
        quantity=new SparseArray<Integer>();

        orderList=new ArrayList<Order>();
        order=new Order();
        Order Null=null;
        for(int i=0;i<fl.foodList.size();i++)
        {
            checks.put(i, false);
            quantity.put(i, 0);
            order.setQuantity(0);
            order.setItem("");
            //orderList.add(i,Null);
            //orderList.add(i,order);
            orderList.add(order);
            System.out.println("Adding at pos:"+i+"Value:"+Null);
        }   
        WaiterFoodAdapter foodAdapter=new WaiterFoodAdapter(this, R.layout.take_order_list, fl.foodList);
        categoryList.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
        categoryList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }
        else
        {           
            System.out.println("Second Adapter:Id="+parent.getId());

            if(view != null)
            {
                final TextView tvItem=(TextView)selectedView.findViewById(R.id.foodName);   
                final TextView tvQuantity=(TextView)selectedView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

                selectedPosition=position;
                SelectFood = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.selectFood);

                if(SelectFood.isChecked())          
                {           
                    SelectFood.setChecked(false);                   
                    checks.put(selectedPosition, false);
                    quantity.put(selectedPosition,0);

                    //order.setQuantity(0);
                    //order.setItem("");
                    System.out.println("Removing at pos:"+selectedPosition+"Value:"+orderList.get(selectedPosition).getItem()+orderList.get(selectedPosition).getQuantity());
                    orderList.remove(orderList.get(selectedPosition));

                    tvQuantity.setText("0");
                    System.out.println("Position="+selectedPosition);
                }           
                else
                {
                    SelectFood.setChecked(true);                    
                    checks.put(selectedPosition, true);
                    System.out.println("Position="+selectedPosition);

                    //orderList=new ArrayList<Order>();                     
                    final AlertDialog.Builder quantityAlert= new AlertDialog.Builder(TakeOrder.this);
                    quantityAlert.setTitle("Quantity");
                    quantityAlert.setMessage("Please enter quantity");

                    final EditText input = new EditText(TakeOrder.this);
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
                    quantityAlert.setView(input);

                    quantityAlert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {   
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                            value = input.getText();



                            if(value.toString().equals(""))
                            {               
                                SelectFood.setChecked(false);
                                Toast msg=Toast.makeText(TakeOrder.this, "Please provide quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                msg.show();       
                            }
                            else
                                if(value.toString().equals("0"))
                                {                       
                                    SelectFood.setChecked(false);                        
                                    Toast msg=Toast.makeText(TakeOrder.this, "Please enter valid quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);                          
                                    msg.show();
                                }
                                else                    
                                {                                   
                                    tvQuantity.setText(value);
                                    quantity.put(selectedPosition, Integer.valueOf(value.toString()));
                                    order.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(tvQuantity.getText().toString()));
                                    order.setItem(tvItem.getText().toString());
                                    orderList.add(selectedPosition, order);
                                    System.out.println("setting at pos:"+selectedPosition+"Value:"+orderList.get(selectedPosition).getItem()+orderList.get(selectedPosition).getQuantity());
                                }



                            //Log.v("Item:",orderList.get(selectedPosition).getItem());
                            //Log.v("Quantity:",String.valueOf(orderList.get(selectedPosition).getQuantity()));

                        }               
                    });

                quantityAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                      {
                          SelectFood.setChecked(false);                
                      }
                    });

                quantityAlert.show();
            }                                           
        }

    }

}
```

When user click addToOrder button it just search for checked checkboxes and gettin relevant textViews values of checked listItems..

```
public void addToOrder(View v)
{
    for(int i=0;i<fl.foodList.size();i++)
    {           
        if(checks.get(i)==true)
            {
            System.out.println("Order is:"+orderList.get(i).getItem()+orderList.get(i).getQuantity());
            }                   
    }
}
```

this is my adapter which is just for custom view purpose

```
public class WaiterFoodAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> 
{
    Context context;
    TakeOrder holder;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<Food> foodList;

    public WaiterFoodAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,List<Food> foodList)
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, foodList);         
        this.context=context;
        this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
        this.foodList=foodList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row=convertView;

        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);
            holder=new TakeOrder();
            holder.foodIcon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.foodIcon);
            holder.tvFoodName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.foodName);
            holder.cbSelectFood=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.selectFood);
            holder.cbSelectFood.setClickable(false);             
            holder.tvFoodDescription=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.foodDescription);
            holder.tvFoodQuantity=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.foodQuantity);
            holder.tvQuantity=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            row.setTag(holder);

        }       
        else
        {               
            holder=(TakeOrder)row.getTag();             
        }
        if(fl.bundleCategory.equals("Appetisers"))
        {
        holder.foodIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.appetiser);
        }
        else
            if(fl.bundleCategory.equals("Main Courses"))
            {
                holder.foodIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.main_course);
            }
            else
                if(fl.bundleCategory.equals("Sides"))
                {
                    holder.foodIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sides);
                }
                else
                    if(fl.bundleCategory.equals("Desserts"))
                    {
                        holder.foodIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.desserts);
                    }
                    else
                        if(fl.bundleCategory.equals("Drinks"))
                        {
                            holder.foodIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.drinks);
                        }
        holder.tvFoodName.setText(foodList.get(position).getMenuItem());
        holder.tvFoodDescription.setText(foodList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.cbSelectFood.setChecked(checks.get(position));
        holder.tvQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity.get(position)));      
        return row;     
    }

}
```

Suppose i select(check) two list items and then press addToOrder button it just prints the last seleccted item twice. I dont know why its just overridding a first object in my List
I think my logic is correct, but dont know why its not working??
Can any one please help

Answer (score 0):

You should make a method in your adapter which lets your update the current arraylist or add/remove the item you pass. But I can't see how you implemented your adapter which probably is the most important code...

You need something like this, inside your adapter (this is to update a full list):

```
public void updateListArray(ArrayList<Item> list) {
    this.clear();
    for(Item item : list) {
        this.add(item);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: if u see my onItemClick method in the else body im checking is the checkbox is not checked,,,so im checking it and also adding the object in the array list in my Alert dialog Ok button fucntion

Comment: yes I see you add the element to orderlist if I'm correct. But orderlist is just a new list... you never add the elements of the list to your adapter.

Comment: i want to add or remove in my List on Check/uncheck condition because i have a apllication which need such kind of implementation

Comment: yes I get that, but you need to tell your adapter that there is some new content to do something with.

Comment: actually im adding Objects of class Order in my List if u see the AlertDialog porting in onItemClick function there are 2 if condition and in else im adding objects of class Order(Class Order is just for getter setter purpose)

Comment: thats all good, but do you have a this.add(item); call inside your adapter? if no then its no go.

Comment: my adapter is updating successfully only problem i have regarding adding and removing objects in my List...@Warpzit

Comment: Is this the list inside the adapter or a global list residing somewhere else?

Comment: actually i dont getting you can you please ellaborate @Warpzit

Comment: it is global list and you can see that i have nothing to do with this list in my adapter @Warpzit

Comment: In my sparseBooleanArray im storing checks as false and true and you can see that in my AddToOrder method im doing the perspective

Comment: might be fl.foodList is confusing you its actually im calling a List of another class and dont worry about that its Working fine

Comment: Well removing the element from a regular list is pretty straight forward. You should consider debugging through it as you probably would have a much easier time doing it than me.

Comment: yeah insteand of removing now im setting to null and also not adding i have try List.set(position,object); but still not working for me..@Warpzit